# Statistical test to compare different treatments over time

Tags: anova, repeated-measures, growth-model

In my experiment I have 4 treatments (the control plus the variables: A, B, C) and I am comparing the growth among them.
I have 4 replicates for each treatment. Thus 16 samples in total.
Every other day, a cell count was made. In the total 11 cells counts for each treatment was made.

In the end, the mean for the replicates in each day were calculated and plotted  [image: Algae Density]. I have 11 density values (means) for the control + 11 density values for the A + 11 density values for the B + 11 density values for the C.

Some data (number of cells in every other day of experiment, i.e. day 0, day 2, day 4,...):

```
Control Means: 111 / 263 / 370 / 460 / 627 / 715 / 802

100x Means:__  101 / 226 / 301 / 408 / 495 / 613 / 668

200x Means:__ 103 / 245 / 296 / 402 / 525 / 614 / 570

400x Means:__ 113 / 229 / 317 / 407 / 613 / 556 / 573
```

The growth rate was calculated and plotted as well [image: Growth Rate]

Some data (growth rate means, µ , between days, i.e. µ mean between day 0 and 2, µ mean between day 2 and 4, µ mean between day 4 and 6,...):

```
Control Means: 0.42 / 0.17 / 0.10 / 0.15

100x Means:__ 0.39 / 0.14 / 0.15

200x Means:__ 0.42 / 0.09 / 0.14

400x Means:__ 0.35 / 0.16 / 0.12
```

I'd like to see if there is any difference among these treatments or if the algae has the same growth independent of the treatment I use.

(p.s.: in the treatments I used waste water diluted in the same seawater I used to prepare the controls using dilutions of 100x, 200x and 400x to grow the algae)

Comment: Is it a case for a two-way ANOVA with repeated measures in one factor (because there are 2 factors influencing the density [cells/ml^2]: treatment and time)? http://graphpad.com/support/faqid/1107/